# DS 160 for family

Tags: visas, usa, paperwork, b1-b2-visas

My husband, my kids age 9 and 4 and I plan to visit US for my brother's wedding.
Can you please advise if we need separate DS-160 form for each one of us as in each separate application or just the 1st applicant can say add family and complete the details or both has to be done fill separate forms and also fill the details by adding family. How do I get everything linked together for payment and visa interview together? I am very confused, step by step help will be much appreciated.